# AWS CDK Update ImageBuilder AMI for EC2 instance, Stack Dependency Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, amazon-ami

I am using AWS CDK to create an AMI via **AWS Imagebuilder** and then deploy that AMI to an **AWS EC2 instance**. I use one stack for AMI ImageBuilder Resources (ImageBuilderStack) and one stack for EC2 resources (EC2Stack). **EC2Stack** calls the AMI image generated in **ImageBuilderStack** to deploy the EC2 instance. However, when I try to update the AMI image in ImageBuilderStack I get the following error:

**Export ImageBuilderStack:ExportsOutputFnGetAttAmiImagebImageIdEB9587C0 cannot be updated as it is in use by EC2Stack**.

How can I resolve this and deploy an updated AMI image? I know my code works if I destroy EC2Stack first and then redeploy it with the updated image. But is there anyway to do this in one go with aws cdk deploy or one AWS cdk cli command? Right now I am trying use **cdk deploy EC2-Stack** or **cdk deploy --all** to update my AMI image and EC2 instance simultaneously.

To modify the AMI I am adding shell commands to **component_documents.test_doc_b.py** (defined below).
To pass the AMI image from ImageBuilderStack to EC2Stack I am using **stack_creator.py**(defined below)

Here is my code:

**ec2_stack.py**

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    Duration,
    CfnOutput,
)

class Ec2Stack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, stacks, stage, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        image_builder_stack = stacks["ImageBuilderStack"]
        iam_stack = stacks["IamStack"]

        image_b = ec2.MachineImage.generic_linux({"us-west-2": 
        image_builder_stack.ami_image_b.attr_image_id}) # Where the ami from ImageBuilderStack is called

        CfnOutput(self, "AmiOutputB", value=image_builder_stack.ami_image_b.attr_image_id)

        test_ec2 = ec2.Instance(self, "Ec2Instance",
            instance_name="deployment_test",
            vpc=shared_vpc_stack.vpc,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_group_name="TestPrivateSubnet"
            ),
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.C5, ec2.InstanceSize.XLARGE9),
            machine_image=image_b,
            role=iam_stack.instance_role,
            security_group=test_security_group,
        )
        test_ec2.node.add_dependency(image_builder_stack.ami_image_b)
```

**image_builder_stack.py**

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_imagebuilder as imagebuilder,
    aws_iam as iam,
)

from component_documents import test_doc_b # shell commands to run in AMI


class ImageBuilderStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, stacks, stage, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        iam_stack = stacks["IamStack"]

       instance_profile = iam.CfnInstanceProfile(self, "InstanceProfile",
           roles=[iam_stack.image_build_role.role_name],
           instance_profile_name="EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilder",
       )

       infrastructure_configuration = imagebuilder.CfnInfrastructureConfiguration(self, "InfrastructureConfiguration",
           instance_profile_name=instance_profile.instance_profile_name,
           name="InfrastructureConfig",
           description="Infrastructure configuration for test AMI image",
           terminate_instance_on_failure=True
       )
       infrastructure_configuration.node.add_dependency(instance_profile)

       yaml_data = test_doc_b.return_test_component_doc()  

       test_component = imagebuilder.CfnComponent(stack, f"testComponent-{image_doc}",
           name="Test-Image-Component",
           platform="Linux",
           version= version, #ie: "1.0.3",
           description="Downloads, installs and configures splunk on Amazon Linux",
           supported_os_versions=["Amazon Linux 2"],
           data=yaml_data  # Arbitrary shell script to generate AMI
       )

       test_image_recipe = imagebuilder.CfnImageRecipe(stack, f"TestImageRecipe-{image_doc}",
           components=[{"componentArn": test_component.attr_arn}],
           name="Test-Image-Recipe",
           # Amazon Linux2 X86 64bit Kernel 5.10
           parent_image="ami-076bca9dd71a9a514",
           version=”1.0.1”, #ie: "1.0.3", iterate up on new releases
           working_directory="/tmp"
       )

       self.test_ami_image = imagebuilder.CfnImage(stack, f"TestAmiImage-{image_doc}",
           infrastructure_configuration_arn=infrastructure_configuration.attr_arn,
           image_recipe_arn=test_image_recipe.attr_arn,
           tags={
               "Name": "test AMI"
           }
       )
```

**component_documents.test_doc_b.py** (Contains shell commands for AWS Image Builder to run in new AMI, gets passed to image builder stack)

```
def return_test_component_doc():
    test_component_doc = f'''
    name: TestDeploymentDocument_B
    description: This is document for downloading, installing and deploying
    schemaVersion: 1.0
    phases:
      - name: build
        steps:
          - name: SetEnvironment
            action: ExecuteBash
            inputs:
              commands:
                - sudo yum update -y 
                - echo “Hello World”
```

**stack_creator.py** (How I deploy stacks and pass ImageBuilder to EC2Stack)

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    Environment
)

from test_stacks.ec2 import Ec2Stack
from test_stacks.image_builder import ImageBuilderStack

from test_stacks.iam import IamStack

class ApplicationInfrastructure(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, **kwargs)

        stage = self.node.try_get_context("stage")
        env_USA = Environment(account=self.account, region="us-west-2")

        ImageBuilderStack = ImageBuilderStack(self, "Image-Builder-Stack", env=env_USA, stage="beta")

        Ec2Stack = Ec2Stack(self, "EC2-Stack", env=env_USA, stacks={"ImageBuilderStack": 
        ImageBuilderStack, “IamStack”: IamStack},stage="beta")
        Ec2Stack.add_dependency(ImageBuilderStack)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Export [...] cannot be updated as it is in use [...]

Stack exports are only appropriate if they are constant values.  You'll need something else to pass variables.

You could populate an SSM parameter and use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types but you'll have to initiate a stack update yourself afterward to pick up the change.

The image builder stack or a shared parent stack could also pass stack outputs to stack inputs without the stack export mechanism.

Comment: How would passing stack outputs from ImageBuilder or ApplicationInfrastructure stack to stack inputs in EC2 Stack that'll let me deploy an EC2 instance look like in code? ApplicationInfrastructure is the shared parent stack. 

Also would this let me get around the error that comes with updating an AMI Image used by Ec2 instace?

Comment: "the error that comes with updating an AMI Image used by Ec2 instace" that's not the error.  The error is that the stack *export* is imported by another stack and thus can't be changed.

Comment: So how would I pass stack outputs from image builder stack or a parent stack to resolve this? And how would that resolve the export issue?

Comment: Instead of using `CfnOutput`, use an input parameter and pass `image_builder_stack.ami_image_b.attr_image_id` as an input

Comment: I could comment out the line `CfnOutput(self, "AmiOutputB", value=image_builder_stack.ami_image_b.attr_image_id)` in EC2Stack, it still gives the same error.